# How to reshape input data for tflearn?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tflearn

I'm trying to reshape my data to be compatible with a tflearn, each row in my data is in the shape (1300, 13). So after I load the data and put each of these (1300, 13) shaped rows in a numpy array like this this:

```
data_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/../data/data.csv'
train = data.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=200)
test = data.drop(train.index)

train_x = train['lowLevel.mfcc'].as_matrix()
test_x = test['lowLevel.mfcc'].as_matrix()

print(train_x.shape) # (8,)
print(train_x[0].shape) # (1300, 13)


train_y = to_categorical(train['category'], len(categories))
test_y = to_categorical(test['category'], len(categories))

train_x = train_x.reshape([-1, 1300, 13, 1])
test_x = test_x.reshape([-1, 1300, 13, 1])

# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 8 into shape (1300,13,1)
```

Not sure what to do here, I'm copying the [MNIST tutorial](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/convnet_mnist.py) from the docs:
their data is in the shape respectively

`train_x train_y test_x test_y
(55000, 10) (55000, 10) (10000, 784) (10000, 10)`

My data's shape is like this (loading only 10 rows until I make it work):

`(8,) (8, 1) (2,) (2, 1)`

When I print `train_x` it looks like this:
[image]

Not sure what's up with all the arrays, since I'm telling Pandas to load the column as a matrix...

The MNIST data can be perfectly reshaped like that:

```
train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y = mnist.load_data(one_hot=True)

train_x = train_x.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1])
test_x = test_x.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1])
```

I'm loading my data from a pandas dataframe and not sure how to shape it like that.

I set up my input layer in tflearn like this:

```
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data
from tflearn.data_utils import to_categorical

net = input_data(shape=[None, 1300, 13, 1], name='input')
```

Does anyone have an idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, had to preallocate arrays:

```
train_x = np.empty((train['lowLevel.mfcc'].size, 1300, 13))
test_x = np.empty((test['lowLevel.mfcc'].size, 1300, 13))

for index, item in enumerate(train['lowLevel.mfcc']):
    train_x[index] = item

for index, item in enumerate(test['lowLevel.mfcc']):
    test_x[index] = item
```